# how to get the indexes of duplicating elements in a ruby array

Tags: ruby, arrays

```
 arr = ["A", "X", "X", "D", "C", "B", "A"}
 arr.detect{|e| arr.count(e) > 1}

 duplicating_value_index_int_array = arr.index(<all duplicating values>)
```

Hi I want to get all the duplicating element's indexes from a ruby array. How may I achieve this?

Comment: `map.with_index` may help you

Comment: Your code is not a valid Ruby code.

Comment: um quite new to ruby still dont know all the functions <> means I need to place necessary codes on it . Thank you :)

Comment: That part is irrelevant. You don't need to know all the "functions" (or methods) to fix your invalid code.

Comment: What kind of output are you looking for? Show based upon your example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 duplicates = arr.each_with_index.group_by(&:first).inject({}) do |result, (val, group)|
                next result if group.length == 1
                result.merge val => group.map {|pair| pair[1]}
              end
```

This will return a hash where the keys will be the duplicate elements and the values will be an array containing the index of each occurrence.
For your test input, the result is:

```
{"A"=>[0, 6], "X"=>[1, 2]}
```

If all your care about is the indices you can do `duplicates.values.flatten` to get an array with just the indices.
In this case: `[0, 6, 1, 2]`

Answer (score 1):

This is quite straightforward implementation. It may be improved greatly, I think

```
arr = ["A", "X", "X", "D", "C", "B", "A"]

groups = arr.each.with_index.group_by{|s, idx| s}.to_a # => [["A", [["A", 0], ["A", 6]]], ["X", [["X", 1], ["X", 2]]], ["D", [["D", 3]]], ["C", [["C", 4]]], ["B", [["B", 5]]]]
repeating_groups = groups.select{|key, group| group.length > 1} # => [["A", [["A", 0], ["A", 6]]], ["X", [["X", 1], ["X", 2]]]]
locations = repeating_groups.each_with_object({}) {|(key, group), memo| memo[key] = group.map{|g| g[1]}} # => {"A"=>[0, 6], "X"=>[1, 2]}
```

Comment: Hi . Is there an easier way in ruby like in python that we can use lambda operations ? Yap its working too . Thank you very much

Comment: I didn't understand the solution you have given here.

Comment: @Priti: yeah, it's quite a mouthful.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Probably I didn't understand the OP's question,thus I also couldn't catch your answer too.. :)

Answer (score 0):

I will assume a valid Ruby array `arr` as follows:

```
arr = ["A", "X", "X", "D", "C", "B", "A"]
```

Under this `arr`, and further assumption that it does not include `nil`:

```
arr.map.with_index{|e, i| i if arr.count(e) > 1}.compact
# => [0, 1, 2, 6]
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear exactly what you want, but this code will find the indices of all elements of an array that aren't unique. It's far from efficient, but probably it doesn't need to be.

```
arr = %W/ A X X D C B A /
dup_indices = arr.each_index.find_all { |i| arr.count(arr[i]) > 1 }

p dup_indices
```

**output**

```
[0, 1, 2, 6]
```